# Adding text to a file 2 lines before the last pattern match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to add a the multi line string in `TEXT` into `myfile.txt` where it last find the text `# My Search`.

If it was a regular pattern replace then `sed` with `i` would do the trick. However I don't know how to go 2 lines above the match in `sed`.

Example, `myfile.txt`:

```
text1
text2
#
# My Search
#
text4
text5
#
# My Search
#
text6
```

`TEXT` looks like:

```
TEXT="
[my search]
home=/var/home
string=random

"
```

`myfile.txt` should look at the end:

```
text1
text2
#
# My Search
#
text4
text5

[my search]
home=/var/home
string=random

#
# My Search
#
text6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -n` to extract the line number, then use it in a sed address to insert the text, which needs to be properly quoted, i.e. there must be a backslash before each newline:

```
line=$(grep -n '# My Search' myfile.txt | tail -n1 | cut -f1 -d:)
((--line))
text=${TEXT//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}
text=${text%$'\\\n'}$'\n'

sed "$line i \\
$text" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**`tac`** + **`bash`** (variable substitution) + GNU **`sed`** approach:

```
txt_reversed=$(echo "$TEXT" | tac)
tac myfile.txt \
| sed -e "N;N;N; s~#\n# My Search\n#~&${txt_reversed//$'\n'/\\n}\n~" | tac
```

The output:

```
text1
text2
#
# My Search
#
text4
text5

[my search]
home=/var/home
string=random

#
# My Search
#
text6
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in one go is to use a tool that can search backward, `ed` is one of them. Ideally you would have the text saved in a file (e.g. `insert.txt`) and insert the file content two lines before the last occurrence of `PATTERN` so you could run:

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
.t.
?PATTERN?-2r insert.txt
$d
,p
q
IN
```

It finds the last occurrence of `PATTERN`, goes up another `2` lines and `r`eads in `insert.txt`. It then prints the content of the buffer via `,p`. Replace that with `w` if you want to edit the file in-place.

---

With other tools that can't search backward a two-pass is the way to go: 1st pass - get the line number and 2nd pass - insert the text content after line `NR-2` or before line `NR-1`. For text saved in a variable I favor `awk` over other tools that rely on regex (the latter require pre-processing the text to be inserted so as to escape any special characters: there are several ones that need escaping, not just the newline, depending on the technique used):

```
export TEXT
awk 'NR==FNR{if ($0 ~ /PATTERN/){c=NR};next}
{if (FNR==(c-1)){print ENVIRON["TEXT"]}};1' infile infile
```

Answer (score 0):

My first contribution in stackExchange.

This is how to insert a line with `sed` before last match.

```
sed -e '/PATTERN[^\n]*/,$!b;//{x;//p;g};//!H;$!d;x;iTEXTOINSERT' FILE
```

This is how to insert a line with `sed` before first match.

```
sed -i -e '/PATERN/{a\\TEXTOINSERT' -e ':a;n;ba}' FILE
```

Regards!

Comment: But does it add the text 2 lines before the last pattern match?