# How to add an average at then end of a table of values

Tags: linux, text-processing, numeric-data

I've been teaching myself Linux for 3 months now and I'm using the `grep` command but I also want an average of all of my extracted values.

Command:

```
grep -o "201[1-4].[0-9][ -9]" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \ | awk -F: '
  {
    if (!s[$1]){ s[$1]=$2 }
    else { s[$1]=s[$1]","$2 }
  }
  END {
    for (f in s){ print f","s[f] }
  }' | csvtool transpose -u " " - | column -nt
```

My current output:

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
2012.69    2013.54    2013.17
2013.44    2013.9     2012.6
                      2013.75
                      2013.08
```

How can I find the average of all 8 values shown here, irrespective of which column they are in?
There are always three columns but the number of rows can't be predicted.

Like so...

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
2012.69    2013.54    2013.17
2013.44    2013.9     2012.6
                      2013.75
                      2013.08
Average: 2013.271
```

This is an example of the content I'm using...

file1:

```
2896.79 2897.65 2898.82 2012.69 2013.44 2897.4  2896.79 2012.64 2896.71 2217.4  2013.11 2012.6  2012.41 2012.41 2013.2  2897.12 2896.61 2896.35 2896.85 2896.26 2896.72
2913.91 2914.41 2914.27 2329.68 2329.71 2914.15 2914.32 2321.19 2914.02 2329.32 2896.49 2025.55 2328.84 2328.98 2329.1  2913.96 2913.48 2913.36 2913.97 2913.46 2913.71
2925.09 2925.58 2926.69 2401.39 2897.65 2925.77 2925.55 2328.96 2924.86 2897.19 2913.95 2029.61 2896.86 2896.93 2764.59 2925.18 2924.96 2924.68 2925.03 2924.18 2924.72
2933.54 2933.91 3196.19 2897.73 2914.79 3314.12 3016.04 2400.29 3015.62 2914.03 2925.09 2897.07 2913.69 2914.41 2897.38 2934.31 3058.51 3015.26 2934.32 2932.55 2933.38
2952.71 2953.49 3223.9  2914.91 2926.03 3321.3  3066.1  2896.71 3065.91 2925.14 2934.16 2914.04 2924.74 2925.54 2914.6  2952.92 3065.18 3065.74 2953.23 3072.91 2952.84
3016.02 3016.4  3249.51 2925.73 2932.82 3373.04 3073.91 2913.87 3073.65 2953.29 2952.94 2925.78 2952.15 2933.65 2925.67 3015.76 3073.21 3072.94 3065.81 3222.86 3015.45
3065.42 3059.27 3313.84 2953.72 2953.17 3444.15 3081.47 2925.02 3192.84 3015.73 3015.47 2953.12 3015.35 2953.29 2953.84 3073.71 3223.42 3080.34 3073.98 3312.09 3059.03
```

file2:

```
2013.17 2012.6  2013.12 2036.82 2037.29 2036.53 2036.44 2032.6  2032.88 2012.76 2037.57 2037.26 2037.5  2042.89 2038.1  2013.75 2037.73 2038    2037.93 2033.5  2033.26 2013.08
2033.07 2033.03 2032.99 2042.08 2042.15 2042.14 2041.82 2036.84 2036.88 2033.27 2042.66 2042.65 2042.61 2461.68 2042.94 2037.45 2042.99 2042.96 2043.04 2037.29 2037.32 2033.44
2037.25 2037.27 2037.26 2080.15 2080.48 2080.35 2079.99 2042.18 2042.22 2037.31 2461.16 2080.81 2080.72 2465.94 2461.39 2043    2081.13 2081.08 2081.26 2042.62 2042.63 2037.55
2042.56 2042.49 2042.41 2464.77 2465.3  2465.08 2460.36 2053.03 2465.1  2042.58 2465.84 2461.76 2460.66 2473.93 2466.23 2461.58 2461.48 2461.6  2466.06 2053.48 2053.35 2042.68
2053.26 2053.42 2053.79 2480.18 2473.43 2472.84 2464.91 2080.37 2480.47 2058.27 2473.22 2465.78 2465.78 2482.02 2474.04 2466.07 2466.05 2466.01 2474.01 2080.88 2080.75 2053.24
2076.01 2059.33 2058.08 2500.19 2481.17 2480.7  2472.76 2460.1  2529.24 2076.3  2481.38 2473.76 2473.51 2501.38 2482.1  2473.97 2474.02 2473.99 2482.05 2276.73 2276.52 2058.42
2080.83 2075.97 2075.97 2529.14 2529.55 2529.28 2481.04 2465.12 2537.59 2080.44 2489.75 2481.63 2481.37 2525.17 2490.26 2482.1  2481.98 2481.96 2501.93 2465.52 2465.58 2076.22
2250.64 2080.54 2080.49 2537.07 2536.95 2537.65 2487.59 2473    2619.65 2276.27 2496.5  2500.38 2489.45 2530.2  2502.23 2525.03 2490.46 2501.06 2530.44 2500.93 2481.26 2080.85
2276.67 2118.71 2275.92 2635.42 2547.03 2544.73 2503.45 2480.94 2636.12 2465.35 2500.25 2524.95 2524.14 2538.07 2524.69 2530.47 2530.45 2524.9  2538.6  2529.88 2500.92 2276.34
```

file3:

```
2207.2  2003.43 6628.01 2013.54 2013.9  2914.93 2003.72 3315.09 2013.66 2013.44 2147.76 2147.67 2207.45 2147.93 2013.89 2013.62 2008.56 2914.99 6632.04
2252.13 2036.51         2147.79 2036.93 2926.08 2013.41 5833.85 2037.51 2037.41 2206.79 2207.16 2898.47 2207.22 2037.11 2147.77 2037.9  3060    
2639.52 2120.66         2206.81 2147.77 3016.02 2036.57 6630.91 2147.94 2147.93 2914.59 2914.66 2915.5  2898.31 2207.46 2206.73 2147.96 3225.13 
2829.69 2147.96         2329.47 2207.1  3059.21 2147.81         2207.22 2207.15 3015.96 3058.98 2926.66 2915.11 2898.69 2329.31 2166.65 3314.22 
2914.74 2206.87         2897.84 2252.53 3225    2329.91         2329.35 2329.69 3031.21 3224.88 3059.82 2926.17 2915.3  2897.89 2207.42 5833.23 
3015.61 2252.38         2914.72 2329.72 3265.74 2897.86         2897.85 2897.81 3058.98 3265.62 3225.63 3059.46 2926.66 2914.67 2253.44 6034.36 
3030.72 2329.24         2925.98 2897.89 3305.35 2914.99         2915    2914.72 3077.57 3305.36 3266.57 3225.4  3016.03 2925.65 2330.06 6121.01
```

Comment: Are there always 3 columns? Never more, never less? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/546738/edit) to say how many columns you expect.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` processing:

```
$ awk '1; NR > 1{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { sum += $i; n++ }}
          END{ printf "Average: %.3f\n", sum/n }' inp_file
```

The output:

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
2012.69    2013.54    2013.17
2013.44    2013.9     2012.6
                      2013.75
                      2013.08
Average: 2013.271
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is only showing me the middle column as an output

Comment: @geom, It works with the output you posted. But your previous commands may potentially get in the way. It would be better if you posted a testable content of your `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` files to restructure your initial pipeline

Comment: Sorry, how do I post testable files?

Comment: @geom, post their contents sequentially in your question in formatted view (like in this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483150/148009)

Comment: Okay I still wasn't sure. Hopefully my last edit helps?

Comment: @geom, Can you clarify the initial idea of your current command?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to identify if a certain value (which is never exactly the same, hence the grepping of a small range) is present in one, two, or three of my samples (the text files). Ideally I would also like to know how many times it appears in each sample but kind of I'm in over my head. Then the averaging is just because... I can't list 15+ numbers for each of my final data points.

Comment: @geom, I see that `file3` has more numbers that match the crucial pattern (like `2013.66 2013.44 2013.41 2013.44 2013.89 2013.62 ...`), but they don't appear in your output, why so?

Comment: I just shortened it for the use of the question. Just wanted to keep it short. Can you tell I'm new to stack exchange ahah